# can webpack modules be loaded that return data or the modules only be ones that execute statements?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

I am trying to implement a client side router in a project app, using vanilla webpack to better understand how webpack works. so the router ive come up with, absolutely simple, loads modules that execute statements fine. however modules that return a string, for instance a string that will be used for a template markup, does not.

**the router**

```
export default function Router(Routes) {

    function loadRoute(routeName) {
        const route = matchRouteObject(routeName)
        route.component()
    }

    const matchRouteObject = function (name) {
        const matchedRoute = Routes.find((route) => {
            return route.name == name
        })
        return matchedRoute
    }

    return {
        loadRoute: loadRoute,
    }
}
```

**routes**

```
export default [
    {
        name: 'root',
        component: () => import('@/app/home/main.js'),
    },
    {
        name: 'canvas',
        component: () => import('@/app/canvasExample/main.js'),
    },
    {
        name: 'svg',
        component: () => import('@/app/svgExample/main.js'),
    },
]
```

**module that loads**

```
export default function home() {
    let constructor = function () {
        const main = document.querySelector('main')
        main.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<h1>your world from root</h1>')
    }

    return {
        init: constructor(),
    }
}

let Home = home()
```

**module that doesnt load**

```
export default function mainSVG() {
    let constructor = function () {
        return '<h1>hello world from svg</h1>'
    }

    return {
        init: constructor(),
    }
}
let MainSVG = mainSVG()
```

and when i tried setting it up to use this module, that isnt loading, i adjust the loadRoute function like

```
function loadRoute(routeName) {
    const main = document.querySelector('main')
    const route = matchRouteObject(routeName)
    main.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', route.component())

}
```

whats happening when i try this is instead of the loadRoute function appending the string returned from the module to the dom, it just reads [object Promise]

Comment: Cause `import(...)` returns a Promise, which will resolve to the actual module value somehwen.

Comment: Ya so I tried handling the promise in the load route function, that didn’t work either

Comment: "didn't work" is no actionable intel.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that when I tried handling the promise in the loadRoute function the only thing printed on the screen was [object Module] where the markup should have been

Comment: Have you tried accessing the `.default` property of that object? It should contain the `export default` of that module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211516/discussion-between-user74091-and-jonas-wilms).